# Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, php

I am using MySQL with PHP for printing details from Database. As i tried to make a new user which was successful though but, i had error from MySQL when i tried to fetch data from it , it showed me this error.

```
    ( ! ) Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in D:\wamp\www\index_feed\index_feed.php on line 8
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  238200  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0024  289384  require_once( 'D:\wamp\www\index_feed\index_feed.php' ) ..\index.php:48
3   0.0024  289672  feed_print( )   ..\index_feed.php:136
4   0.0024  291264  mysqli ( )  ..\index_feed.php:8
```

The dilemma here is i am even not using "root" user and yes i do have a password for user, but in the error it is showing `using password : NO`. I am totally stuck in here, i think it's a problem with `using password` .

I have tried using root for fetching data, but it doesn't work. The same error showed up.